# IE10 max-width fails on image inside fixed layout table columns

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, width

When trying to restrict an image to a `max-width` of `100%`, the `max-width` property fails to work in IE10 when inside a `table cell` with a set `width` and a `table-layout: fixed`.

How can I force this while maintaining the `table-cell` display properties?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/christianmagill/pen/bZAjqE)

```css
.row {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.photo,
.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.photo {
  width: 25%;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
.text {
  width: 75%;
}
HTML <div class="row"> <div class="photo"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/sports/1/" alt="" /></div> <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio facilis debitis sequi hic iusto nostrum fugiat. Temporibus rem repellendus,
officia,
asperiores perspiciatis delectus labore odio iste voluptatum consectetur quibusdam magnam deserunt,
ea ipsa eos quidem. Aperiam iste voluptate expedita illum,
suscipit animi quas eum sed omnis reiciendis optio molestiae maiores sunt voluptates,
ad. Pariatur rem similique,
cupiditate impedit a iure odio laboriosam quaerat in magni vel at incidunt ratione corrupti quod repellat quo,
vitae veritatis et magnam doloribus mollitia tenetur? </div> </div> .row {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.photo,
.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.photo {
  width: 25%;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
.text {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/sports/1/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio facilis debitis sequi hic iusto nostrum fugiat. Temporibus rem repellendus, officia, asperiores perspiciatis delectus labore odio iste voluptatum consectetur quibusdam magnam deserunt, ea
    ipsa eos quidem. Aperiam iste voluptate expedita illum, suscipit animi quas eum sed omnis reiciendis optio molestiae maiores sunt voluptates, ad. Pariatur rem similique, cupiditate impedit a iure odio laboriosam quaerat in magni vel at incidunt ratione
    corrupti quod repellat quo, vitae veritatis et magnam doloribus mollitia tenetur?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

This happens because you have your `table` also with `max-width` and
because `img` is an inline element.

### Explanation

`min/max-width` won't apply to non replaced inline elements.

[W3C specs says:](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths)

> 10.4 Minimum and maximum widths: `min-width` and `max-width`
>
> `max-width`
>
> **Applies to:**   all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table
>   rows, and row groups

### Possible solutions:

- you can just set it `width:100%` in `img`

or

- set `width:700px` in `table`

```css
.row {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.photo,
.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.photo {
  width: 25%;
}
.photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.text {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/sports/1/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio facilis debitis sequi hic iusto nostrum fugiat. Temporibus rem repellendus, officia, asperiores perspiciatis delectus labore odio iste voluptatum consectetur quibusdam magnam deserunt, ea
    ipsa eos quidem. Aperiam iste voluptate expedita illum, suscipit animi quas eum sed omnis reiciendis optio molestiae maiores sunt voluptates, ad. Pariatur rem similique, cupiditate impedit a iure odio laboriosam quaerat in magni vel at incidunt ratione
    corrupti quod repellat quo, vitae veritatis et magnam doloribus mollitia tenetur?
  </div>
</div>
```

### Note

Also occurs in IE11.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I am wondering why changing the image's display property to block wouldn't solve the issue. Would it then be solely because of the max-width of the "table"?

Comment: yes would be because of the `max-width` applied to table.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, instead of:

```
.photo{
  width: 25%;
   img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

try:

```
.photo{
   width: 25%;
}
.photo img{
   max-width:170px; /* Or another size*/
   width:100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Besides separating the two elements, this says "Make my image 100%, unless it's bigger than 170px. Tested in IE as well.